# Should private key files be checked-in in git?

Tags: git, version-control, project-management

In my understanding, git as version control system should track all resources or files that are necessary to build a software version.

If a private key file is needed for a server to function correctly (say to communicate with client that has the public key we distribute), then, should this private key file be tracked in git or somewhere else?

Comment: Is _the_ key needed to build the software at all, _a_ key needed to build the software and _the_ key blesses it as official or is the key needed to get a particular installation do what it should?

Answer (score 8):

No it should not.

A key has different specifications to source code or program.

**The product should not work without a key**
It is *specification of product* that it does not work without a key. If you include the key in the distribution you effectively destroy its use.

**A key should be easily replaceable.**
 In fact, sometimes it's needed to regularly replace it. And sometimes a deploy of a new version is a difficult and long process. Combine that with the need to rebuild your project to get a new key, and you have the recipe for a perpetual headache. If you *do not* require a rebuild to get the new key, then there is *no reason* to put the key into git - it's not used in building, bundling or testing your app.

**Consider code audits.**
An auditor needs to have access to source code to verify logic (and sometimes to a working program). They are *not* supposed to see (and hence be able to memorize) your private keys. I'm not going to go through whether it's realistic to memorize a 2048-bit key by glancing at it - sometimes reviews are done remotely.

**A key does *not* need a history.**
A key is *not* tied to the version of the software in most cases. Key change dates and reasons may be interesting, but those do not need to be available to everyone.

**Keys are issued per company or per server, not per application.**
Should you ever decide that you need a second server in another country with different laws and a different key, or allow a different company to run your server software as well, this is most important. Those should have *different* keys. Bundling your key with the app is a no-go then.

**Keys should not be public information**
Does your intern really need to have access to your production server key? Really? Does your compliance/security department concur?

There is but one key that you may want to include in Git - a test key for an internal test server or a local server. That will ease initial deployment and allow you to change key formats without making a company wide email asking all devs to change their local keys as well, while *not* invalidating the actual security and integrity of your production server.

Answer (score 5):

As always, this is a non-obvious question only because there are several valid principles in conflict.

The one is that you should version-control everything that is needed to build the project. This is rather important. The other is that secret information should be passed out on a need-to-know basis to minimize the probability of data breaches. This can be extremely important or less important depending on what the consequences would be.

Since you know the circumstances of your organization better than we do, you must make the judgement call about that trade-off. We can only tell you how important things are *in general*.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a *private* key it git, it is no longer private. If you don't mind that happening, then do it. If you want to keep the private key private, don't publish it on a public server.

Instead, check in to git instructions on how someone can generate and use their own private key.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better not, for security reason. Or everyone can access `git` can get the private key.

A better way may be to put private key and public key somewhere with internet access. Each client can get public key directly without authorization. And the server will get the private key with authorization. It's just a bit thought, since I'm not the export for the domain.

But if the private key kept in `git` is only for test but not real product, I think it's fine.

Comment: I concur.  There's a difference between software program and *its configuration.* The private key belongs in the second group.  And since it must be kept secret (no entity beyond the program and its admins must have access to it) it should not be a part of the repository.

Comment: And how do you _authenticate_ the public key if the client gets it from the internet? Sorry, that advice sounds extremely off. -1 for that part.

Comment: @kostix: There are keys that are part of the source, not configuration. It depends how the key is used (and the question only gives limited details).

Answer (score 0):

If *the* key is needed to build or run the software *at all*, then it is part of source and should be versioned. But I don't think that's common case.

If *a* key is needed to build or run the software, but *the* key is needed to designate the build as official release, then *the* key should live on the build server. In version control should be a method used for generating a valid key for testing or a particular key for use in testing. *The* key may be itself versioned, but not together with the project, because the team members don't actually need it, only the build server or the release manager do.